# Sending SMS through low end API

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a message constructor method of the form:

```
public static String constructMsg(CustomerInfo customer) {
    ... snipped 
    String msg = String.format("Snipped code encapsulated by customer object");

    return msg;
}
```

The API link is:

http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/bulksms?username=xxxxxxx &password=xxxx &type=0 &dlr=1&destination=10digitno & source=xxxxxx& message=xxxxx

In my main method I have(s):

```
List<CustomerInfo> customer = dao.getSmsDetails(userDate);

        theLogger.info("Total No : " + customer.size() );

        if (!customer.isEmpty()) {

            for (CustomerInfo cust : customer) {
                String message = constructMsg(cust);

                // Add link and '?' and query string
                // use URLConnection's connect method 
            }
        }
```

So I am using `connect` method of URLConnection. The API does not have any documentation. Is there any way for checking response?

My other question is, I have been advised to use ThreadPoolExecutor. How would I use use it here?

Comment: This makes no sense. `constructMsg(` takes an argument that it doesnt use. Why??

Comment: Edited code I have only added the important bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method use HTTPURLConnection to perform a GET request returning the response as a String. There're many way to do it, this is not particularly brilliant but it's really readable.

```
public String getResponse(String url, int timeout) {
    HttpURLConnection c;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new              InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
       default:
        return "HTTP CODE: "+status;
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DebugServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DebugServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally{
       if(c!=null) c.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Call this method like this:

```
getResponse("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080/bulksms?username=xxxxxxx&password=xxxx&type=0 &dlr=1&destination=10digitno&source=xxxxxx&message=xxxxx",2000);
```

I assume the whitespaces in your URL are not supposed to be there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is 200 http code condition left blank? And could you expand on the 201 code? I feel Threads are not needed for this.

Comment: 200 and 201 are handled by the same case. 201 is returned on success by some backend API so I included it in the answer.

Comment: Oh how could I miss that switch semantic! Thanks. Btw would this work with the method call wrapped in a loop?

Comment: I edited the code to close HttpURLConnection in the finally clause. I haven't run the code (I just wrote it down in the editor) but the point is to be sure to release the connection in the finally clause. With this precautions you can be safely use it in a loop.